# Jquery Datatables overriding default value to disable Prev and Next pagination options

Tags: jquery, jsp, spring-mvc, datatables

I am using DataTables.

I don't want "`Previous`" and "`Next`" option visible (at least not clickable) on the page when only one page is displayed.

How can it be achieved?

DataTable Code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var jq = jQuery.noConflict();
    jq(document).ready( function(){
        jq("#results").dataTable({
            "aaSorting": [[ 5, "desc" ]]
        });
    });
</script>
```

I tried

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').dataTable( {
        "sPaginationType": "full_numbers"
    } );
} );
```

But it starts showing a lot other options and disable the buttons.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you have any demo fiddle? that will be more than understanding.

Comment: Added the code snippets. It should help.

Answer (score 0):

You should add [fnDrawCallback](http://datatables.net/usage/callbacks) function to your datatable code:

```
"fnDrawCallback": function( oSettings ) {
    if ( $('#example_paginate span a').size() > 1) {
         $('#example_paginate')[0].style.display = "block";
    } else {
        $('#example_paginate')[0].style.display = "none";
    }
}
```